# iOS6 breaks default autorotation and landscape in cocos2d 1.0 beta

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

In the default cocos2d 1.0 beta template, AppDelegate.m has some code:

```
// AppDelegate.m
// IMPORTANT:
// By default, this template only supports Landscape orientations.
// Edit the RootViewController.m file to edit the supported orientations.

#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    [director setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
#else
    [director setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#endif
```

Next, In GameConfig.h, we have defined:

```
// GameConfig.h
#define kGameAutorotationNone 0
#define kGameAutorotationCCDirector 1
#define kGameAutorotationUIViewController 2
//
// Define here the type of autorotation that you want for your game
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController
```

Together, this was working to produce a landscape setup that auto-rotated to either landscape-left or landscape-right depending on how you held the device. TableViews autorotated as well (I have several tables placed on top of some cocos2d CCScenes).

However...I updated to iOS6 last night. As well as XCode 4.5.

I'm hoping it's not just me, but my app's rotation is completely broken now. I'm trying to fix it via code for at least one tableview...changing GAME_AUTOROTATION seems to have no affect on tableviews, just the cocos2d CCScenes (which is half of the solution in a way).

I may just start from scratch and get something built up instead of working with pre-written code, this is just mega-frustrating!! Thanks a lot, Apple!

Comment: It's the way cocos2d v1.x is set up to perform autorotation which broke with iOS 6. More info: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/40721 and here http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/33326 Btw, as a developer you should expect breaking changes when upgrading to new versions. It's Apples right to change things, it's your responsibility to check if any of these changes might conflict with your app or the software/libraries you are using.

Comment: I'm not here to start a war on what is and isn't acceptable practice in the developer community, but that second half feels condescending. I'm doing everything I can to make things work and resolve conflicts in my code that are producing undesirable results across devices.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to upgrade my stuff to cocos2d 2.0 and to remove the dependency on the RootViewController, which is no longer used.

```
navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];
```

Answer (score 1):

My partial solution is

```
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    //[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
#else
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#endif
```

Do you have a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Check out cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/40721. Partial answers should not be posted like this. Have a read of stackoverflow.com/faq